# Rsync unable to remove remote file not exist in local

Tags: rsync, wildcards

Consider my local folder

```
/tmp/foo/
/tmp/foo/1.txt
/tmp/foo/2.txt
/tmp/foo/3.txt
```

and my remote folder

```
/tmp/foo/
/tmp/foo/1.txt
/tmp/foo/2.txt
/tmp/foo/4.txt
```

and in my local side, I run the command in the `/tmp/foo` folder

```
rsync --exclude=3.txt -avcz --delete * ubuntu@server:/tmp/foo/
```

I was able to sync my files except `3.txt`, but `4.txt` is remote still exists, why?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't delete `4.txt` because you are running the `rsync` command with `*`, i.e. on the individual source files. Hence, `rsync` doesn't even consider `4.txt` (or the containing directory). Instead, run it on the directory that contains the sources, by changing the `*` to `.` Then, `rsync` can look at the directory as a whole as see what is missing.

```
rsync --exclude=3.txt -avcz --delete . ubuntu@server:/tmp/foo/
```